# How Do I Create a Blogger Static Page Listing Recent Comments?

Tags: widget, comments, blogger

I have a blog hosted by Blogger. http://www.rocketstackrank.com

I want to add a tab for "Recent Comments" because I think the "Comments widget" is buried on the side and doesn't show enough comments anyway. I'm thinking that if I give people a specific page that lists dozens of comments, I'll get more people responding to them.

Ideally I'd do this by somehow re-purposing the existing recent comments widget. I'm comfortable with HTML, CSS, JQuery, etc. Otherwise, I'm planning to write a C# app to use the Blogger API to extract the comments and then create the page dynamically. (And manually run that program once a day or so.)

But surely there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your new static page for comments and edit the page in "HTML" Mode.

Then you can paste a script like this to display recent comments:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
function showrecentcomments(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numcomments; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var alturl;
        if (i == json.feed.entry.length) {
            break;
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                alturl = entry.link[k].href;
                flagAnon = !1;
                break;
            } else {
                // anonymous commenter
                alturl = "http:\/\/www.rocketstackrank.com\/?showComment=#";
                flagAnon = !0;
            }
        }
        var postlink = alturl.split("?showComment=");
        postlink = postlink[0];
        if ("content" in entry) {
            var comment = entry.content.$t;
        } else
        if ("summary" in entry) {
            var comment = entry.summary.$t;
        } else var comment = "";
        var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        comment = comment.replace(re, "");
        if (!standardstyling) document.write('<div class="bbrecpost">');
        if (standardstyling) document.write('<br/>');
        if (flagAnon = !1) {
            document.write('<a href="' + alturl + '" style="text-decoration:none">' + entry.author[0].name.$t + ':' + '</a>   ');
        } else {
            document.write('<a href="' + alturl + '" style="text-decoration:none">' + entry.author[0].name.$t + ':' + '</a>   ');
        }
        if (showposttitle == true) document.write(' in ' + posttitle);
        if (!standardstyling) document.write('</div><div class="bbrecpostsum">');
        if (standardstyling) document.write('<div class="txtmsg"><br/></div>');
        if (comment.length < numchars) {
            if (standardstyling) document.write('<span style="word-break: break-word;">');
            document.write(comment);
            if (standardstyling) document.write('</span>');
        } else {
            if (standardstyling) document.write('<span style="word-break: break-word;">');
            comment = comment.substring(0, numchars);
            var quoteEnd = comment.lastIndexOf(" ");
            comment = comment.substring(0, quoteEnd);
            document.write(comment + '...<a href="' + alturl + '">(Read more)</a>');
            if (standardstyling) document.write('</span>');
        }
        if (!standardstyling) document.write('</div>');
        if (standardstyling) document.write('<br/>');
    }
    if (!standardstyling) document.write('<div class="bbwidgetfooter">');
    if (standardstyling) document.write('<div style="height:6px;width:100%;"></div>');
    if (!standardstyling) document.write('</div>');
}
// Params
var numcomments = 5;
var showposttitle = false;
var numchars = 70;
var standardstyling = true;
//]]>
</script>
<script src='//www.rocketstackrank.com/feeds/comments/summary?max-results=5&alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentcomments'></script>
```

Make sure that the param `numcomments = INTEGER` (within the script) it's equal to `max-results=INTEGER` in the callback script.

With param `numchars = INTEGER` you can set the lenght of the comment preview.

Publish your page keeping Blogger editor in HTML Mode.

As final suggestion, inspect the HTML output and style as desired and add/remove objects according to what you want to display.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!